# Patch a class - that is an attribute of an other class - to access its methods

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I am trying to mock an attribute of a class `Bar` upon creation of its instance object `test_obj`. The attribute is an instance of another class called `Foo`.
Afterwards, I want to test a `bar` method from `Bar` class  which is calling a `search` method of the `Foo` class.

I am having this `error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'search'`. I understand it might be because I am mocking the `foo` attribute of `Bar` class with the str as `MockedFoo`.

My question is: how can I change my mocks so that I can access the methods of `Foo` class via the `foo` object of `Bar` class? The `search` method further must return a list (which I'm able to do) but I am unable to access this method first.

Here is my code:

```
import unittest
from mock import patch


class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 'foo'
    
    def search(self):
        # do something

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = "123"
        self.name = "abc"
        self.foo = Foo()

    def bar(self):
        return self.foo.search()
    

def test_bar():
# initialization of Bar object
    with mock.patch('lib.lib_foo.Foo', return_value="MockedFoo")
        test_obj = Bar()
    test_obj.bar()
```

I have read a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31709792/patching-a-class-yields-attributeerror-mock-object-has-no-attribute-when-acce) but that is for the access of the field. I am unable to adapt my code for accessing the methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the instruction `with mock.patch('lib.lib_foo.Foo', return_value="MockedFoo")` in your `test_bar()` method, and I have set a list as return value for the method `search` of the mock object created.

Below there is my code:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 'foo'

    def search(self):
        # do something
        pass

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = "123"
        self.name = "abc"
        self.foo = Foo()

    def bar(self):
        return self.foo.search()

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_bar(self):
        test_obj = Bar()
        with patch.object(test_obj, 'foo') as mock_foo:
            mock_foo.search.return_value = ['my', 'test', 'list']
            self.assertEqual(['my', 'test', 'list'], test_obj.bar())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Note that the `test_obj` object is created before the context manager `with ...`.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I didn't know how to mock a field. Much appreciated